# Is there any replacement of Top in Sql dependency in signalr?

Tags: sql, signalr, sqldependency

Can you please let me know how can i use Top or other sql statement in sql dependency to get Top 5 records, whenever i use this Top its always shows Sql NotificationType Subscribe.

Please help me out to get top records using query in SignalR

When i tried this its is working fine

```
public void SendStocksNotifications(string symbol="")
        {
            string conStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnectionString"].ToString();
            using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conStr))//"data source="";initial catalog="";persist security info=True;user id="";password="";multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;"))
            {
                string newdate = DateTime.Now.ToString( "MM/dd/yyyy" );
                string query = "SELECT TOP 1 [Close],Pre_Close, Volume, Pre_Volume, PercentageChange, Pre_PercentageChange, NetChange, Pre_NetChange, High, Low, Pre_High, Pre_Low,Previous, Pre_Previous, [52WH], [52WL] FROM [dbo].[History] WHERE Symbol='" + symbol + "' ORDER BY UpdatyedDate DESC";
                 connection.Open();
                 using ( SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( query, connection ) )
                 {

                 }
        }
    }
```

But this code

```
private void dependency_OnChange1(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            string symbol = Vsymbol;
            NotificationStocks nHub = new NotificationStocks();
            nHub.SendStocksNotifications( symbol );
        }

    }
shows e.Type=SqlNotificationType.Subscribe.
```

Comment: Please reply on the same.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Note that SQLDependency does not give you details about the changed records, it just notifies something has happened with the data specified in your query.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are trying to achieve.